# How to install PHP composer on Windows docker image?

Tags: php, windows, docker, powershell, composer-php

I am trying to install Composer on a Windows Docker image

Dockerfile is provided below

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019

RUN powershell.exe Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://getcomposer.org/installer" -OutFile composer-setup.php
RUN powershell.exe Start-Process -FilePath "php.exe" -ArgumentList composer-setup.php
```

However, when I build the docker image it does NOT either install `composer` or throw any error

I tried to install composer setup using the following methods but none worked

```
1)  RUN powershell.exe Start-Process -FilePath "php.exe" -ArgumentList composer-setup.php
2)  RUN powershell.exe Invoke-Expression "'php.exe composer-setup.php'"
3)  RUN powershell.exe Invoke-Expression "php.exe composer-setup.php"
4)  RUN powershell.exe Invoke-Expression -Command "'php.exe composer-setup.php'"
5)  RUN powershell.exe Invoke-Expression "& 'php.exe' composer-setup.php"  - & not allowed error message
```

Kindly let me know how to execute `php.exe composer-setup.php` using `Powershell` or `CMD` from within the Docker container.

**EDIT**

I connected to docker image

```
PS C:\Users> docker run -it myphp:latest
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.1935]
(c) 2018 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

and executed the following but nothing happened instead it returned to prompt

```
C:\Softwares\Composer>php.exe composer-setup.php
'php.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Softwares\Composer>C:\Softwares\PHP\php.exe composer-setup.php

C:\Softwares\Composer>
```

Comment: Why not download the PHAR directly?

Comment: Or maybe even try [the Windows installer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows), although I do not know if it supports running unattended. (More sanely though, abandon Windows to run PHP).

Comment: @yivi Thanks for your help.  Windows installer does not support unattended installation.  However, not sure why composer-setup.php was not executed

Comment: Again, just download the phar.

Comment: @yivi How to download composer.phar ?

Comment: If you do not have PHP installed in the image, everything else is moot, isn't it?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? `'php.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command` - looks like PHP isn't even installed?

Comment: @NicoHaase Kindly look at the line which is below the error message

Comment: What do you mean by that? There's nothing written below that line, so I don't get what you are referring to

Comment: @NicoHaase You can see that php.exe (just below the error message) returned to prompt without executing composer-setup.php.  Simple php.exe --help also did not work.

Comment: And what have you tried to resolve the problem? Calling `php.exe` from within `C:\Softwares\Composer` is different to calling `C:\Softwares\PHP\php.exe`

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried both the ways and nothing worked.  I am not sure how to proceed further

Answer (score 0):

I added the following to Dockerfile and it worked fine

```
ADD vcruntime140.dll C:\\Windows\\System32\\vcruntime140.dll
```

Unlike Windows host machine (where DLLs exists by default) we need to explicitly add the requires DLLs to Docker